# Robot and sensor are out of map bounds (Local Costmap- Voxel Layer)

Tags: ros, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am at this step [footprint](https://navigation.ros.org/setup_guides/footprint/setup_footprint.html) step of tutorial of NAV2. However I am configuring for my specific robot.
Given that I have different dimensions, range for lidar and map size, I have configured different values for [mapping](https://pastebin.com/8nCnbUdN)  (mapper_params_online_async.yaml) and for the [costmaps](https://pastebin.com/HbnDw0yA) (nav2_params.yaml)

1 - I launch my **display.launch** file,  Rviz and Gazebo is opened properly with the lidar set correctly (at least in terms of Transform and subscribing /scan messages)

2- Secondly I launch the **online_async_launch.py** launch file and get no errors:

```
INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/rota/.ros/log/2023-05-04-19-40-07-815644-NUC-21912
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [async_slam_toolbox_node-1]: process started with pid [21914]
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1683240007.920155126] [slam_toolbox]: Node using stack size 40000000
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1683240008.344782676] [slam_toolbox]: Using solver plugin solver_plugins::CeresSolver
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1683240008.345652180] [slam_toolbox]: CeresSolver: Using SCHUR_JACOBI preconditioner.    INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/rota/.ros/log/2023-05-04-19-40-07-815644-NUC-21912
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [async_slam_toolbox_node-1]: process started with pid [21914]
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1683240007.920155126] [slam_toolbox]: Node using stack size 40000000
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1683240008.344782676] [slam_toolbox]: Using solver plugin solver_plugins::CeresSolver
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1683240008.345652180] [slam_toolbox]: CeresSolver: Using SCHUR_JACOBI preconditioner.
[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] Registering sensor: [Custom Described Lidar]


[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] Registering sensor: [Custom Described Lidar]
```

3- I launched the **navigation_launch.py** . Unfortunately in this step the error is raised:

**[planner_server-2] [WARN] [1683239305.550661960] [nav2_costmap_2d]: Robot is out of bounds of the costmap!
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1683239305.598894226] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Sensor origin at (-4.23, 0.02 3.09) is out of map bounds (25.74, 29.99, 3.86) to (-15.05, -15.05, 0.00). The costmap cannot raytrace for it.**

I checked that this error raises from the costmap voxel plugin function (rows 318-328) : [voxel_layer.cpp](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/galactic/nav2_costmap_2d/plugins/voxel_layer.cpp)

I have already changed the following parameters:

- Map size
- Laser Range (from 15 to 100)
- Global and Local Costmap values (resolution, width, height, origin_x, origin_y, maximum height, etc)

I wonder if this costmap error is raised because my lidar is **pitched to the ground** (**Lidar Orientation,  Position)**, so the range in x direction is smaller than at y direction, or is it my Lidar in a too high spot ? over truck's cabin...

Gazebo
[image: image description]

Rviz2

[image: image description]

As you can check the global costmap is drawed properly and its footprint as well

However the **local costmap** is not generated and its respective footprint also not!
In this way the path planner won't work well (at least the obstacle avoidance)...since I don't have the local costmap

What can be leading to this error?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415039/robot-and-sensor-are-out-of-map-bounds-(local-costmap--voxel-layer)/) by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2023-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After an extensive investigation involving adjusting various parameters in**nav2_params.yaml** and experimenting with different positions and orientations of the LiDAR sensor, I discovered that the issue was not related to the sensor's range, pose, FOV, or any other related factors.

The root of the problem lies in the configuration of the**slam-toolbox** package. For some reason, it was misconfigured and did not work properly with the local costmap and voxel layer.

When running a **static** transform publisher (map --> odom):

```
ros2 run tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom
```

Both local and global costmaps are generated, but the map itself is not produced:

image description

[image: image description]

Adjustments were made to the Voxel map range (width, height), and the raytrace range was increased to better suit the robot's dimensions and the environment's size.

However, when running the slam **dynamic** transform (map --> odom) using :

```
ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_sync_launch.py
```

The map and global costmap are generated, but the **local costmap** is not (even for the TurtleBot3 Waffle tutorial example or for my robot):

[image: image description]

A closer examination of the /tf topic reveals differences between the transforms when using the slam-toolbox async node and the static transform.

1. slam-toolbox async node:

   transforms:

   - header:
     stamp:
     sec: 47
     nanosec: 381000000
     frame_id: map
     child_frame_id: odom
     transform:
     translation:
     x: 3.4662790218048424e-06
     y: -2.2171464780663484e-07
     z: -0.400019324960254
     rotation:
     x: -2.7712992106286824e-07
     y: -4.332639404341957e-06
     z: 1.1986118037611005e-12
     w: 0.9999999999905756
2. static transform:

   ---

   transforms:

   - header:
     stamp:
     sec: 33
     nanosec: 92000000
     frame_id: odom
     child_frame_id: base_link
     transform:
     translation:
     x: -0.02042282951343617
     y: -0.014272684253787292
     z: 0.8999813856701359
     rotation:
     x: 3.8079219550742497e-08
     y: 3.443628320324917e-06
     z: -0.0021973022911122857
     w: 0.9999975859224768

When using the **static transform,** there is no periodic transform published between the map and odom frames. I suspect that the local costmap plugin might rely on this transform (although I'm not certain), and when using the slam mapping node, the periodic transform between the odom and map frames may interfere or overlap with the static transform, potentially causing conflicts.

It's unclear how the [Voxel grid plugin](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/galactic/nav2_costmap_2d/plugins/voxel_layer.cpp) code is integrated with the slam-toolbox and how it affects the local costmap generation. Further investigation into the interplay between these components is needed to pinpoint the exact cause of the issue.

In summary, the problem seems to stem from the slam-toolbox configuration and its interaction with the local costmap and voxel layer. A thorough investigation of the relevant components and their interdependencies could potentially reveal the root cause and offer a more permanent solution.

---

Originally posted by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) with karma: 266 on 2023-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0